# Good Speech Recognition Programs for disabled people

Tags: accessibility, speech-recognition

I am trying to help my friend, who is severely disabled due to autism. I have found out that speech recognition is a good interface for disabled people to interact with the computer.
One good software which is available in Windows XP is [e-speaking](http://www.e-speaking.com/) software which uses Microsoft Speech API and provides a nice interactive way to use the computer.

One friend who has good cognitive abilities has made efforts to use e-speaking voice recognition and is able to use his computer effectively.

But, I am looking out for another friend, who needs much more motivation to try the speech recognition.  I am trying to look for certain motivating examples.

1. Games which can be played using speech recognition.
2. Software suitable for children studying in 6th-8th grade and which might keep them interested.
3. Software which girls might like and which might have voice input too. [Story telling Alice](http://www.alice.org/kelleher/storytelling/index.html) comes close, but it does not have voice input.

We also have a Vista computer, but the speech recognition in Vista does not have a voice feedback (when compared to e-speaking) and as I said, the person I am talking about will be more motivated when there is a voice feedback from the computer, so i see e-speaking as the better solution.

I am yet to try Dragon Voice recognition.

If you get my explanation, can you suggest some software that can be operated via voice also will be a motivational one for a young girl.

Comment: +1 Fascinating subject. I'll look forward to some answers and will try to provide some of my own. But now... bed time.

Comment: I wish that I could give more useful information. I used to train disabled people to use Dragon Dictate, but the people I dealt with were adults who had either physical disabilities (preventing them from typing) or dyslexia. I have no experience with children or autistic people. Dragon Dictate worked well for the people I was assisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approaching the problem from another direction:

Can your friend operate a mouse or a joystick? [Dasher](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/dasher/) is a very useful text input system (tell him it's like driving for letters) and you can hit about 30WPM once you've practiced enough.

It will also learn to predict your input. If your friend doesn't want to try Speech-To-Text, have them try that. People who can barely move are able to write with this system, but it may also present a different interface for your friend who has cognitive disabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bram. I am visiting Super User after sometime. Yes, one of my friend is using dasher for text input. But not through regular mouse or joystick (They cannot hold it), but one was trying with camera mouse. It became difficult to control the cursor using camera that we resorted to voice based. Now, he using voice to control dasher too (we have not gone far with this tough).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play one of the vista card games with vista's speech recognition software and it was really hard and I had to use the mouse is several ocations.

I've used Dragon Naturally Speaking and it's great for dictating texts, but wasnt much helpful to control the PC.

Don't know about any games that could be played with speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

There is at&t natural speaking engine but I don't know if that's what your looking for.